# .Net MVC assigning ViewBag value to JavaScript script variable issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I am trying to send a string value from my controller action on my view using View Bag like this

```
 public ActionResult Services()
    {

        ViewBag.TabVal = "EarnMoney";
        return View();
    }
```

On my view I am assigning the View Bag value to a JavaScript variable like this

```
 @section scripts{

<script>
    var tab = @ViewBag.TabVal;
    console.log(tab);
 </script>
}
```

on my console I get this value

```
    <li id="EarnMoney"> EarnMoney</li>
```

which is an HTML element on my view.

Why is it selecting the element on my view and not giving a string in return ?This is really weird behavior.

Comment: Do we have all of the code here, cause this wouldn't happen from the code shown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You output viewbag value directly to javascript, without the quote, so it's not a string in javascript.
Html generated from server looked like this:

```
var tab = EarnMoney;
```

and since there's a dom element with that id, it selects that element instead

Put your ViewBag output in quote like this instead:

```
var tab = "@ViewBag.TabVal";
```

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> var tab = @ViewBag.TabVal;
> ```

When the Razor engine renders the view, the @ expression is replaced directly:

```
var tab = EarnMoney;
```

and thus the value will be whatever the JavaScript engine sees in the variable/property `EarnMoney`.

You need to put the quotes in what substituting in a literal string:

```
var tab = "@ViewBag.TabVal";
```

Comment: I noticed this, but this doesn't explain to me why it would output as HTML in the console

Comment: @Coulton it doesn't. I suspect that `EarnMoney` is defined JS value at that point (eg. the same – missing quotes – defect could appear elsewhere).

Comment: Sorry @Richard but EarnMoney is not defined any where as a JS variable ,the ViewBag assignment without quotes always tries to select an element with that id and if the element does not exists in HTML it gives an error,I did not continued the discussion  because I thought you guys told me that this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

you can get value from view bag by using quote and @ sign

```
var tab = '@ViewBag.TabVal';
```